# Local deployment of cloud foundry wont connect to CF APi endpoint

Tags: cloud-foundry

[root@localhost cf-release]#  cf api --skip-ssl-validation  https://api.10.244.0.34.xip.io
Setting api endpoint to https://api.10.244.0.34.xip.io...
FAILED
Server error, status code: 404, error code: 0, message:

whenever i run the command to target API endpoint the same error appears

What I have tried and do:

1. Fresh install at least 4 times
2. ssh on all containers is possible even the one with api
3. I can ping to all containers
4. verify that all containers are up and running using **bosh cck**
   command
5. api target request traffic reaches proxy container successifully

when i user browser  to access  i get

404 Not Found: Requested route ('api.10.244.0.34.xip.io') does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do

```
$ cf api api.bosh-lite.com --skip-ssl-validation
```

Not `api.10.244.0.34.xip.io`.

Comment: thanx. But does it mean i have to create an account on bosh-lite.com

Comment: No.  bosh-lite.com is not a special service, it's just a DNS record created by the core CF development team which resolves to 10.244.0.34 for convenience of anyone trying CF on BOSH Lite.